# Getting Google+ business page ID based on vanity URL

Tags: google-plus

We are looking to implement `rel=publisher` to verify our website against our Google+ page.

However, according to the [Rich Snippets tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets), this only appears to work with a numeric page ID: e.g. https://plus.google.com/103037366582313115962/

However, we have a vanity URL https://plus.google.com/+TheGuardian

How can I find out our numeric page ID based on a Vanity URL?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, worked this out:

- Go to https://plus.google.com/ as a Google+ user.
- Search for your page using the search box
- Copy the link location of the search result for your page. e.g. `https://plus.google.com/u/1/113000071431138202574`

...The last fragment of the URL is your Google+ page id

Comment: You can also grab your page ID by clicking on the timestamp of any post you have made.  Your page ID will be used in those permanent posts, rather than the vanity ID.

Answer (score 3):

In order to get the 21 digit ID from a vanity URL, you need to utilize people.get API!

Just enter the vanity URL portion with the plus sign (for example +Name) as the userId [here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.people.get?userId=%252BTeslaMotors&_h=1&) and scroll down to the 'Response' section to get your id.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the G+ page
2. Press `Ctrl+U` then `Ctrl+F`
3. Type data-oid.
   ex: data-oid="101059889519664604142"

Answer (score 0):

You just have to do is right click on on name (page name or person name) select Copy Link Address & paste it in a new Tab you will see the code as my is https://plus.google.com/+InzimamTariq

but when I do that this is in return.

https://plus.google.com/109309640886924591969

hope you like it & it will help you

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to -> www.Google.com
2. [Press] +UserName where "UserName" is your user name
   *(usually your email is UserName@google.com)*
3. Hover over **Home** in top left for drop down menu
   Just below Home you should see **Profile**  <- click on **Profile**
4. Check your URL and if should look like this:
   https://plus.google.com/u/0/+UserSetUrl/posts
   *or*
   https://plus.google.com/u/0/12398987468276/posts

   - The +UserSetURL is your google+ profile name.
   - If you have not created your own specific URL / ID then the numbers are your ID.
   - You should change the Numbers to something easy like MyName or UserID so you won't have to do this ever again.

**Note**: This is according to UI as of April 28, 2015